# Test Class for Trigger need high code coverage

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, class, code-coverage

I wrote a trigger that functions properly. I just need test class for I can move it to production. Here is the barebones of the trigger.

```
trigger triggerName on Sponsorship__c (events) {
    if (event) { // trigger.isUpdate, trigger.isBefore, etc
        Map<Id, Sponsorship__c> contactToSponsorship = new Map<Id, Sponsorship__c>();
        Lisit<Contact> contactsToUpdate = new List<Contact>();

        for (Sponsorship__c s : trigger.new) {
            contactToSponsorship.put(s.contact__c, s);
        }

        for (Contact c : [SELECT Child_Names__c FROM Contact WHERE Id IN :contactToSponsorship.keySet()]) {
            c.Child_Names__c += contactToSponsorship.get(c.Id).Sponsored_Child_Name__c;
            contactsToUpdate.add(c);
        }

        update contactsToUpdate;
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far in in your test class? Are there any particular lines you are having trouble getting coverage for?

Comment: How can this work? event is not valid as a parameter??. If this is not the full code, aside from the fact that it is off topic, how do you expect anyone to write a proper test method?

Comment: If you're new to unit testing, I'd highly recommend going through the [Apex Unit Testing module on Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/apex_testing). It probably won't give you all the knowledge that you need (and that's where questions on this site come into play), but working through this yourself will make you much better at unit testing than if someone were to just give you the answer outright.

Comment: Won't you get a npe at `c.Child_Names__c += ...` if `Child_Names__c` is null?

Answer (score 0):

```
@isTest(seealldata=false)
private class testclasssample{
  @testsetup
  static void createtestdata(){
    Account acc = new Account();
    Acc.name = 'test account';
    Insert Acc;

    Contact ct = new Contact();
    ct.account = acc.id;
    ct.Child_Names__c ='test child name';
    ct.name= 'test contact';
    Insert ct;
 }
 static testmethod void test1(){
    List<Contact> collContacts = [select id from Contact where name = 'test contact'];
    Test.startTest();
    Sponsorship__c newSponsorship = new Sponsorship__c();
    newSponsorship.Name='test sponsorship';
    newSponsorship.Sponsored_Child_Name__c = 'sponsored child name';
    newSponsorship.contact__c = ct.id;
    Insert newSponsorship;
    system.assertnotEquals(null,newSponsorship.id);
    newSponsorship.name = 'Test sponsorship updated';
    Update newSponsorship;
    Test.stopTest();
 }
```

}

Comment: Code dumps don't do much to help the person, whom asked the questsion, to learn. They also aren't very helpful to people who may come to this question in the future. This answer would be improved if you explained what was going on, and how exactly it solves the problem of the given question.